# Batch File Comparing Database backup with condition

Tags: batch-file

I would like to ask about this matter i want to backup the database table every 10mins and compare with the existing database table.
here

```
@echo off

set tbluser=user_tbl
set tblticket=ticket_tbl
::REM set Date 
set datetoday=%DATE:~10,4%%DATE:~4,2%%DATE:~7,2%

for /F "tokens=5-8 delims=:. " %%i in ('echo.^| time ^| find "current" ') do (
    set hh=%%i
    set mm=%%j
)
set datentime = %datetoday%%hh%%mm%
::set path
set dBackup="D:\dbBackup\dailybackup"
set wBackup="D:\dbBackup\weeklybackup"
set zip="C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe"

FC /B %wBackup%\%tblticket%.sql %dBackup%\%tblticket%_%datentime%.sql

IF %wBackup%\%tblticket%.sql EQU %dBackup%\%tblticket%_%datentime%.sql (DEL %dBackup%\%tblticket%.sql) ELSE (%zip% a -tgzip %dBackup%\%tblticket%_%datentime%.sql.gz %dBackup%\%tblticket%_%datentime%.sql
    del %dBackup%\%tblticket%_%datentime%.sql)  


@pause
```

Comment: Does your code work?  If not then some more explanation than what you have provided would be useful.

Answer (score 0):

1 - I don't know how to backup your database. No info included.

2 - You get the current date from `%date%` environment variable. Do the same for time with `%time%` variable

3 - To test for equality of the two files, after using FC to compare, check errorlevel to know if command failed or not

```
FC /b file1 file2 > nul
if errorlevel 1 (
    rem files are different
) else (
    rem files are identical
)
```

Comment: Hi!..

Another question how to select all items on a folder??

Comment: Assuming "select" is enumerate, and "all items" are all files, and its the current dir, and ... a lot of assumptions, `for %%f in (*) do echo "%%~ff"` BUT it depends on what you need to do. Try, and when you find problems, make a question and share them with us.

Comment: hi i have another question about

FC /B %wBackup%\%tblticket%.sql %dBackup%\%tblticket%.sql
if errorlevel 1 (
 echo complete
 ) else (
 echo failed
 )
if my record are the same the code of FC /B %wBackup%\%tblticket%.sql %dBackup%\%tblticket%.sql is not working its not comparing

Comment: FC is used to compare file contents. It does not understand sql, nor record structure. Just check if the two files have exactly the same content byte by byte. If it doesn't work as expected, use another tool to do the compare or change backup procedure to generate the exact same content if there is no data changes. FC will only test if files are identical, same size, same content.

Comment: Question ca you give me sample of backup code where you can compare the first that already backup and the second one.. i need that kind of backup for knowing what the table has been updated in certain hrs.

Comment: It depends on your database server and on your database schema. No way for giving you a generic code to do that. Anyway, comparing backups seems not the logic way for knowing which changes has beed done in data. If this changes are critial, logging data change seems a better approach. What if data is changed, then code executed, decissions taken, and data reverted to original, all between backups? Comparing backups will not show anything.